Unusual windows decration behavior / not working properly
UPDATE: see note at bottom
I have a seemingly bizarre situation.  When I click the windows decorations in the upper right corner of the window (the maximize / minimize / close icons), then either it does nothing, or it launches an unrelated program.  And what is stranger, is that this only occurs if the icons are in an area about 1" x 1" in the right upper corner of the desktop.
I have tested by taking various applications and positioning the top right corner step by step.  Outside this zone, everything works fine.  Inside the zone is malfunctions.  I tried changing the launcher dock from the left side of the screen to the right, but this just shifts the zone out enough to accommodate the dock.  I have a 2nd screen, and I tried moving its positioning around, and it seemed to have no effect.
The unrelated program that it launches (sometimes), is AnyDesk (https://anydesk.com).  So I thought that perhaps this program had done something to my system on its installation. So I uninstalled it and rebooted the computer.  Then when I click on the icons, it doesn't launch AnyDesk, but is also just does nothing when the icons are in the mysterious ~1"x1" zone.
I have set this computer up for my wife, who is a Linux skeptic, and she loves to run her programs in full screen mode.  Unfortunately, this always puts the close button in the zone, and she is not amused when she tries to close, for example, Firefox -- only to have AnyDesk launch.
I did some web searching and couldn't find anything mentioned about a similar situation.
Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance,
Kevin
P.S.
System information:
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS  (recent install, no modifications.  Only change made was to remap the super key so it could be sent through AnyDesk)
OS type: 64 bit
Windowing system: X11
Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic
Gnome version 46
Memory: 16 GiB
Processor: i5-6600Kx4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics530 (SKL GT2)
Graphics 1: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070
Disk capacity: 1 TB
Computer Mode: ASUSTek Comp Inc, Z170 PRO GAMING/AURA
UPDATE:
As I was writing this post, StackExchange was busy trying to find similar posts.  If found this one: Anydesk freezes (clicking not working) a portion of right side upper corner in ubuntu 23.04  And that seems to describe my same problem.  I don't want to lose everything I have written up, so  I will post this, but I am also going to try the suggestions posted there.

The other post fixed it!  See Answer below.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I don't know how to do that.  I was as detailed with my question as possible, and ended up finding an answer which I shared as an answer.

On this thread:
Anydesk freezes (clicking not working) a portion of right side upper corner in ubuntu 23.04
The answer by Kasetiya Yash dated July 19,2023 fixed my problem.
It involves renaming
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js
to change the extension from .js to .bak  (I changed my to .js.bak) and then rebooting.
